# How to recover from exception when debugging python?

Tags: python, pycharm, pydev, pdb, ipdb

When stepping through the code in pdb, any exception hit immediately ends the program. How do I instead fix the exception and keep debugging? Is there no way to avoid the overhead of restarting the program?

It seems like many py debuggers share this annoyance: pdb, ipdb, pycharm, pydev.

Comment: You could catch the exception, run `pdb.post_mortem()` in the `except` block to poke around a bit, and then execution will continue since the exception has been handled.